# CSS overflow / z-index issue - marker not shown in SAFARI

Tags: html, css, safari, overflow, z-index

it seems my brain is a bit overloaded. I can't figure out why a "marker" isn't shown correctly in Safari - in chrome instead, it's working fine.

I believe it is an overflow issue, as the property is not set everywhere.
I have already tried to set overflow: visible and a proper z-index via the Safari Dev tools, but no luck so far. I hope you guys can enlight me.

The issue is on following website http://apop.burningpips.com/
If you scroll down to the "community" section (CSS class - please open inspector), you can see that all items have a "marker" on top of the item (latest blog posts). The marker on the first item is like cropped out in Safari.

Basically, we have:

```
<section class="attractions">[...]</section>
<section class="community">
  <div class="prompt top">[...]</div>
  <div class="prompt bottom">[...]</div>
  <div class="container">[...]</div> <!-- This should overlap all -->
  <div class="cta-container wood wood2">[...]</div>
</section>
```

The "container" div contains the code with the incorrect marker. I can't explain to myself why this is not working. Please visit in Safari and Chrome to see the difference.

I hope I gave all necessary Information. If not, please let me know if I can do anything further.

thanks in advance.

Comment: appears perfectly in both browsers on my computer. What version of safari?

Comment: Hey, thanks for checking. I'm running Version 10.1 (12603.1.30.0.34). The issue has resolved.

I'm writing a new comment now for those who interest.

Comment: great, thanks for update.

Answer (score 0):

after trying all variants of setting overflow: visible and z-indexes, I found the issue:

it has been the css properties for the div with class "post-container"

--> column-count: 2;

--> -webkit-column-count: 2;

I have added a margin-top to the first blog-post item, and a margin-bottom for the last item.

That helped.

Thanks everybody for looking into this.